# Error with Jenkins installation on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins, installation

I'm trying to install Jenkins on an Azure VM with Ubuntu 20.04 following the next command lines:

```
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > \
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install jenkins -y
```

But when I try to install Jenkins with the last command, this happens:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  jenkins
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 91.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 95.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ jenkins 2.332.3
  Redirection from https to 'http://mirrors.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins_2.332.3_all.deb' is forbidden [IP: 146.75.30.133 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/binary/jenkins_2.332.3_all.deb  Redirection from https to 'http://mirrors.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins_2.332.3_all.deb' is forbidden [IP: 146.75.30.133 443]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Read the [blog lpost](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2022/05/13/mirrors/). If you need more help, raise a [Community issue](https://community.jenkins.io/c/contributing/infra/5) or file [Jenkins Infra issue](https://www.jenkins.io/projects/infrastructure/)

Comment: @IanW this is an issue with packages from `https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/` redirecting to `http://mirrors.jenkins.io/debian/` -- do you think the redirect can be updated to point to `https` instead? (and/or the instructions on https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/ updated to point to mirrors instead?)

Comment: (I filed an issue: https://github.com/jenkins-infra/jenkins-infra/issues/2191)

Comment: It has been [identified](https://community.jenkins.io/t/failed-to-fetch-https-pkg-jenkins-io-debian-stable-binary-jenkins-2-332-3-all-deb-redirection-from-https-to-http-mirrors-jenkins-io-debian-stable-jenkins-2-332-3-all-deb-is-forbidden-ip-151-101-158-133-443/2575/2) as caused by [pkg.jenkins.io certificate expired - varnish cache reports #2957](https://github.com/jenkins-infra/helpdesk/issues/2957) and [Update "mirrors.jenkins.io" references to use https #2192](https://github.com/jenkins-infra/jenkins-infra/pull/2192)

Answer (score 2):

I actually solved the problem, I don't know why with the actuall Jenkins installation guide it doesn't work but i solved it with these 2 command lines:

```
wget https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/binary/jenkins_2.332.3_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i jenkins_2.332.3_all.deb
```

I've been trying with some versions till I found the one that worked, and now Jenkins is working.

https://deb.pkgs.org/packages/jenkins/jenkins_2.332.3_all.deb.html

Answer (score 1):

Before installing Jenkins, you need to do,

```
sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get update
```

Then install,

```
sudo apt-get install jenkins -y
```

Answer (score 0):

(Ubuntu 22.04)
I have installed "**net-tools**" manually and just after that "**Jenkins**" has started to install.
Accordingly, I've changed my Ansible yaml

```
---
- name: Install dependencies
  apt:
    name: net-tools
    state: present

- name: ensure the jenkins apt repository key is installed
  apt_key:
<skipped>
```

Answer (score 0):

it was solved for me,

1. i'm running ubuntu 20.04 in AWS EC2 NEW instance
2. first command that im used in it

   *sudo su -* (to enter the root user)
3. Update the repository

   *apt update*
4. Install net-tools

   *apt install net-tools*
5. Install JAVA, 'cause the jenkins can be running with JAVA

   *apt -y install openjdk-11-jdk*
6. Edit the Java's path

   *find /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11** (copy the output of that command)
7. Add JAVA PATH

   *nano /etc/environment* (Open the file)
   *JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64"* (add this command)
   *CTRL + X* and *Y* and *ENTER* (for save that file)
8. Reload the file

   *source /etc/environment*
9. And check the PATH

   *echo $JAVA_HOME* (the output will be pretty same like step number 6)
10. Those were the requirement before you install the Jenkins
11. Download the jenkins file

    *wget https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/binary/jenkins_2.332.3_all.deb*
12. And then install it

    *dpkg -i jenkins_2.332.3_all.deb*
13. The installation will be success, now you can see your jenkins in EC2

    *[your-ip-public]:8080* ('cause the jenkins is run with 8080 port, we need add new rule of securtiy group in our EC2 instance)

I hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

You can install Jenkins with docker via docker-compose.

```
  version: "3.1"
  services:
    jenkins:
      image: jenkins:latest
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
        - 50000:50000
      volumes:
        - jenkins-home:/var/jenkins_home
  
  volumes:
    jenkins-home:
```

Before installation -> `sudo apt install docker.io docker-compose -y`

Comment: If you check https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins, you'll see the `jenkins` image you're referencing is deprecated; what you probably wanted instead is `jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11`.